# get count in joining multiple table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 tables named user, group and user_has_group. I am joining these tables using eloquent. Everything is working just fine, but I need something more. I need to figure it out that which group has how many users. Here the I code I have used:

```
$result = UserHasGroup
                ::join('group', 'user_has_group.group_id', '=', 'group.id')
                ->join('user', 'group.created_by', '=', 'user.id')
                ->where('user_has_group.user_id', '=', $user -> id)
                ->select("user.name as created_by",
                    'group.created_at',
                    'user_has_group.user_id',
                    'group.name as group_name')
                ->getQuery()
                ->get();
```

and here's the response:

```
{
    "successful": [
        {
            "created_by": "TUSHAR13",
            "created_at": "2018-05-11 18:04:38",
            "user_id": "5",
            "group_name": "DSGJA"
        },
        {
            "created_by": "TUSHAR13",
            "created_at": "2018-05-11 18:10:17",
            "user_id": "5",
            "group_name": "V76OL"
        },
        {
            "created_by": "TUSHAR13",
            "created_at": "2018-05-10 00:00:00",
            "user_id": "5",
            "group_name": "qwerr"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I can't understand where to add groupby and count query. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = UserHasGroup
                ::join('group', 'user_has_group.group_id', '=', 'group.id')
                ->join('user', 'group.created_by', '=', 'user.id')
                ->select("user.name as created_by",
                    'group.created_at',
                    'user_has_group.user_id',
                    'group.name as group_name', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->groupBy('user_id')
                ->getQuery()
                ->get();
```

You have to use `DB::raw('Count(*)')` in the `select()` then use group by user_id.

hope this helps.

Comment: its giving me another error:

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tushuxem_meal_system.user.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `user`.`name` as `created_by`, `group`.`created_at`, `user_has_group`.`user_id`, `group`.`name` as `group_name`, count(*) as total from `user_has_group` inner join `group` on `user_has_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id` inner join `user` on `group`.`created_by` = `user`.`id` where `user_has_group`.`user_id` = 5 group by `user_id`)"

Comment: turn off the strict mode

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM turn off the strict mode.

Comment: its working, but its giving me wrong answer.
group qwerr should have 2 members. But it showing me: 
`{
            "created_by": "TUSHAR13",
            "created_at": "2018-05-10 00:00:00",
            "user_id": "5",
            "group_name": "qwerr",
            "total": "1"
        }`

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM you have only one user in each group

Comment: no,
here is the table user_has_group data:

`user_id    group_id 
5              1
5              2
5              3
5              4
4              3`

Comment: I cant paste the code here. ok, there are 2 members in group id 3

Comment: your code is working when I am removing `->where('user_has_group.user_id', '=', $user -> id)` these line. Its Showing the right data

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM yess it is using the where condition that's why it is showing only one record

Comment: but that's not what i need.